# Creating Generic Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a Key value pair the key is a string and the value is a class. The whole is thing is accesses through a generic method. So when I do a search based on the Key I get the class value in the dictionary. But unfortunately the code I have written compile it gives the below error. TokenizeCardViewModel' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

So when I do something like this :

`bool value = CreditCardDetailPathCollection().Contains(subPathValue)`

I Should get true or false. So that I can later use the value of the dictonary to create instance of the class.

```
private Dictionary<string,T> CreditCardDetailPathCollection<T>() where T:class
{
   return new Dictionary<string,T>
   { 
      { "tokenize-card", TokenizeCardViewModel } 
   };
}
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: you probably need to create a new instance `new TokenizeCardViewModel ()` but that unless `TokenizeCardViewModel` is derived from T you will still have problems.

Comment: Tried but get error. cannot convert from TokenizeCardViewModel to T

Comment: Noted that in my previous comment. Can you explain what it is you are trying to achieve so that proper help can be provided.

Comment: I get that you are trying to create generic dictionary. What I do not get is how `{ "tokenize-card", TokenizeCardViewModel }` plays into the what you want to do.

Comment: Does the provided answer address your current problem?

Comment: Why not just use object? Dictionary<string, object>()

Comment: @maxspan Ok after looking this over I get the impression that you are trying to make some kind of factory/service provider?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
private Dictionary<string, T> CreditCardDetailPathCollection<T>() where T : class
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); 
        return new Dictionary<string, T>
        { 
            { "tokenize-card", obj } 
        };
    }
```

Below code will create the instance of the T

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```

This way you just need to call the CreditCardDetailPathCollection method like this

```
var dict = CreditCardDetailPathCollection<TokenizeCardViewModel>();
```

Comment: using the `new()` constraint should work as well. allowing `new T()` instead of using activator.

Comment: @Nkosi I tried that getting this error: Can't create the instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new(0 constraint

Comment: Did you include the constraint `where T : class, new()`

Comment: While this does… something… I’m not sure if this is what OP would be trying to achieve here. It would be somewhat weird to have `CreditCardDetailPathCollection<SomeTypeThatHasNothingToDoWithCards>()` return a dictionary where an object of that type is at the key `tokenize-card`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understand that problem.

1. You have a K/V pair which is actually a `string` / `Type`.
2. Given a `key`, you are returned a `Type`.
3. Given the `type`, you now create an instance of this type.

Here's some code that might help...

NOTE: I also made this [little .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xhOA9Y) so you can see it in action

```
var myTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
myTypes.Add("Leia", typeof(User));

...

if (!myTypes.ContainsKey(key))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Dictionary failed to contain the key: {key}");
    return;
}

var myType = myTypes[key];
Console.WriteLine($"Found the type: ${myType.ToString()}.");

try
{
    var something = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to create an instance of {myType.ToString()}. Why? Error Message: {exception.Message}");
}
```

Now this assumes that there is a `default constructor` for the class which you wish to dynamically create an instance of.